# Move text to the left on hover image

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have some *text* I want to move to the *right* when I'm *hovering* over an *image*:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="info-over">
    <div class="infoText">
      Text that need to move to the right
    </div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Avatar" class="image">              
  </div>
</div>
```

I want that the *div* `infoText` moves slowly to the *right* `50px` when I'm *hovering* the *image*, and that when I stop *hovering* the *image*, it moves slowly backwards.

Tried with *transitions*, but it won't work for me, maybe you guys can help?

Comment: Show the css you tried please (plus any starting css you may have on the items) - please read [MCVE]

Comment: You'll need CSS, something like `.info-text { transition: margin-right all 0.2s; } .infoText:hover { margin-right: 50px; }`. That probably won't work perfectly straight away but should be a good starting point. Maybe set up a jsfiddle so we can help you demo it?

Comment: or you can use `.infoText:hover { transform: translateX(50px); }`

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n8ybh7da/ @TomOakley

Comment: @JoelStüdle Thats what i want, but how to put a lenght on it? Like 2 seconds? Now it goes immediatly 50px to right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with *Flexbox*, *positioning*, `order` *property*, and the *adjacent sibling combinator* (`+`) to *target* the `.infoText` *div*:

```css
.info-over {
  display: inline-flex; /* takes only the content's width */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks flex-items (children) vertically */
}

.infoText {
  order: -1; /* places the text above the img to achive the same display/layout as before */
  position: relative; /* positioned relative to its normal position */
  top: 0; /* default */
  left: 0; /* default */
  transition: left 1s linear; /* adjust */
}

.image:hover + .infoText {
  left: 50px;
  transition: left 1s linear; /* adjust */
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="info-over">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Avatar" class="image"> <!-- moved it above the text so that you can use the + selector to target the element below -->
    <div class="infoText">Text that needs to move to the right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way with the `transform: translateX()`:

```css
.info-over {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.infoText {
  order: -1;
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.image:hover + .infoText {
  transform: translateX(50px);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="info-over">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Avatar" class="image"> <!-- moved it above the text so that you can use the + selector to target the element below -->
    <div class="infoText">Text that needs to move to the right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I recommend you to use the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
$(".image").hover(function(){
$(this).closest('div').find('.infoText').animate({
    'marginLeft': '+=100px'
}, 500);
}, function(){
$(this).closest('div').find('.infoText').animate({
    'marginLeft': '-=100px'
}, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="info-over">
    <div class="infoText">
      Text that need to move to the right
    </div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Avatar" class="image">              
  </div>
</div>
```

Add the proper CSS too. The solution is a bit repetitive, but works!